# EF Core - no database update on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

today I've got a little surprised that my `SaveChanges()` method of DbContext didn't work as expected.

Here is the method I used to get user data from Db:

```
        public async Task<UserModel> GetUserByIdAsync(string Id, bool editMode)
        {
            if (editMode) return await UserDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(usr => usr.UserId == Id);
            else return await UserDbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(usr => usr.UserId == Id);
        }
```

And here is the method that was supposed to update the entity in Db:

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateUserDataByAsync(UserModel updatedUser, ClaimsPrincipal currentUser)
        {
            var user = await GetUserByIdAsync(updatedUser.UserId, true);
            user = updatedUser;
            return await UserDbContext.SaveChangesByAsync(currentUser) > 0;
        }
```

Also `SaveChangesByAsync` method is just overriden `SaveChanges()` to automatically update some Db columns like `UpdatedBy`:

```
public async Task<int> SaveChangesByAsync(ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal,
                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var entries = ChangeTracker
                    .Entries()
                    .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseModel && (
                            e.State == EntityState.Added
                            || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

                foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
                {
                    ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = now;
                    ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedBy = userPrincipal.FindFirstValue("UserId") ?? "Anonymous";

                    if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = now;
                        ((BaseModel)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = userPrincipal.FindFirstValue("UserId") ?? "Anonymous";
                    }
                }

                return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return await Task.FromCanceled<int>(cancellationToken);
            }

        }
```

Eventually I overcame this problem by changing `UpdateUserDataByAsync` to the following content:

```
            UserDbContext.Entry(await GetUserByIdAsync(updatedUser.UserId, true)).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedUser);
            return await UserDbContext.SaveChangesByAsync(currentUser) > 0;
```

But I would like to ask you why the initial version didn't work? Since the user was pulled without `AsNoTracking()` modifier, shouldn't the context keep tracking any change, which in this case was a simple replacement of `user` data with `updatedUser` data?

Thank you!

Comment: `user = updatedUser;` overwrites a reference but does not tickle the change tracking.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thank you! So is this approach only useful if I know which property has been changed to avoid manual updating user directly? Should I in all other cases go for `CurrentValues.SetValues`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code much simplier:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateUserDataByAsync(UserModel updatedUser, ClaimsPrincipal currentUser)
        {
 UserDbContext.Entry(updatedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
 return await UserDbContext.SaveChangesByAsync(currentUser) > 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. How would then `UserDbContext.Entry(updatedUser)` find the right user that needs to be updated? Does it check by Id?

Comment: Yes, It  uses generic overload functios to find type  and Id of object. It properly works only if your entity  has a primary key.